# Why are $e^{-4\ln(-x)+4}$ and $e^{-4\ln(-x)}$ positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

> Algebraically, why is $e^{-4\ln(-x)+4}$ a positive result but $e^{-4\ln(-x)}$ a positive result?

It seems like with logarithmic properties, they should both be negative, but Wolfram Alpha shows the graph and states that it must be positive. Is there a logarithmic identity to explain this discrepancy? Thanks much!

Comment: $e^u>0$ for *any* real number $u$ [positive, negative, or zero.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^y > 0$   for all $y$ which means that it is also the case for $y=-4ln(-x)+4$ and $y=-4ln(-x)$ means $e^{-4ln(-x)+4} > 0$ and  $e^{-4ln(-x)>0} >0$ there where they are defined.

Comment: Thanks very much! Does that mean that we would have to write any algebraic answer of e^ln(some expression) as (some expression) with absolute value signs around it?

Comment: No: e.g $e^{\ln(-x)}$ is defined only when $x < 0$. In that case, the result is $-x = |-x|$ since both are positive. But it would be a mistake to say that $e^{\ln(-x)} = |-x|$ if $x \ge 0$, since the LHS is *not* defined in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the former as $$e^{-4\ln(-x) + 4} = e^{-4\ln(-x)} \cdot e^4 = e^{\ln((-x)^{-4})} \cdot e^4 = \frac{e^4}{x^4}.$$ Notice that this will always be nonnegative.

Similarly, you can write $$e^{-4\ln(-x)} = e^{\ln((-x)^{-4})} = \frac{1}{x^4},$$ which will still be nonnegative.

Comment: Where has the red negative sign has gone? $e^{\ln(\color{red}-x^{-4})} \cdot e^4$

Comment: @callculus I was editing the post, I noticed the formatting issue, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for writing out all those steps! I’m confused about the last step. In a simpler question, like e^ln(-x), I thought that the answer would be -x (negative).

Comment: @Yelena Just note that $e^{a\log b} = e^{\log (a)^b},$ and that $e^{\log c} = c.$ Therefore, $e^{\log (a^b)} = a^b$

Comment: ln(x) is only defined for x> 0.  In order that ln(-x) exist, x must be **negative**1!